# osmdroid maps tiles not showing on a ldpi screen

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have an app that uses osmdroid. Everything works fine on my Galaxy Nexus but when I try it on a Galaxy Mini the map tiles don't load. The URL call gets fired correctly but I only see the background full of squares... any idea?